# query for first and last day of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have the name of the month, how can I have the first and last day of that month in SQL?

I have this query to returns the month names:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName
FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Result:

[image: results]

Now, how can i get the first and last day of that months? changing the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :-

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
        @EndDate    DATETIME;

SELECT   @StartDate = '20110501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20110801';


SELECT  DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS MonthName,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),
DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate))-1),DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)),101) as FirstDay,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)))),DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate))),101) as LastDay
FROM    master..spt_values x
WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

Result :-

```
 MonthName       FirstDay         LastDay   
  May           05/01/2011        05/31/2011    
 June           06/01/2011        06/30/2011    
 July           07/01/2011        07/31/2011    
 August         08/01/2011        08/31/2011
```

Result obtained taking the help from [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/13/sql-server-query-to-find-first-and-last-day-of-current-month/) query

Answer (score 8):

If you want a more general and simple solution:

```
DECLARE @startdate AS DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT      
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @startdate) , 0)   as startMonth,
DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, 1,  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @startdate) , 0) ) ) as endMonthExactly,
EOMONTH(@startdate) as endMonthDay
```

Gives the result:

```
startMonth       2023-12-01 00:00:00
endMonthExactly  2023-12-31 23:59:59
endMonthDay      2023-12-31
```

Answer (score 2):

This code gives you the **first date of Current Month:**

```
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

If you know the **Month's number** then:

```
SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + @MonthNumber, 0)
```

Same goes for **Month's end date** :

```
SELECT   DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -1,
         DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - @@MonthNumber+ 1, 0))
```