# Convert character string to date in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, varchar, date-conversion

I need to convert character string to date format to fetch the first and last day of the month.

Input.

DECLARE @InpDat AS VARCHAR(20)
SET @InpDat = 201308

Expected output 2013-08-31

I need to get the first and last day of the given yearmonth. Can you please help me to get that.

I tried with the convert option but couldnt get it. ?

Comment: Yes. But the input will be like yearmonth format [ for e.g 201308 ]

Comment: possible duplicate of [query for first and last day of month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742605/query-for-first-and-last-day-of-month)

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST(@InpDat + '01' AS DATE)` to convert it to a date and [`DateAdd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for the date arithmetic.

```
DECLARE @InpDat AS VARCHAR(20) SET @InpDat = '201308'
DECLARE @Month DATE SET @Month = CAST(@InpDat + '01' AS DATE)

SELECT @MONTH AS First, 
       DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 1, @MONTH)) AS Last
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/7023/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InpDat AS VARCHAR(20) 
SET @InpDat = '201308'

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME(@InpDat+'01') AS FirstDate,
       DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,CONVERT(DATETIME(@InpDat+'01'))) AS LastDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect that a random number will convert to a date format without any cajoling?  The database is a powerful tool but not magical.

You have to parse the number into a date, then format the date the way you like.  I might suggest this sequence of calls:

```
-- assume you can separate the year and month into separate parts.
-- use 01 as default day for now, we'll get last day shortly.
DECLARE @IntermediateDate AS DATE SET @IntermediateDate = DATEFROMPARTS(2013,08,01)
-- Advance the month by one, and subtract one day to find the last day of the month.
SET @IntermediateDate = DATEADD( dd, -1, DATEADD( mm, 1, @IntermediateDate))
```

Now format using your favorite formatting functions.

Comment: `DATEFROMPARTS` isn't available on SQL Server 2008, it's an SQL Server 2012 function